# Configuring GIT in Oracle SQL developer 18.x

Tags: database, oracle, git

First of all please accept my apologies if my explanation is poor but I'll do my best to be as clear as possible.

**Situation**: I have access to a database only via connection so no local copy to initialize GIT.

**Question**: Is it possible to have a local copy of the source DB in order to initialize the GIT repository AND also, for the developers, after cloning from the GIT, is it possible to work on there local copy and have those changes reflected on the source DB.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at https://gitora.com/